# How to concatenate datepart in SQL Server?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2014

I am trying to make a master calendar in SQL Server. I am facing the problem with this syntax:

```
[dateid] as DATEPART(YEAR, [date]) & DATEPART(day, format( [date],'DD')) & DATEPART(month, format([date], 'MM')) 

[dateid] as convert(varchar(4), DATEPART(YEAR, [date])) + convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(day, format( [date], 'DD'))) + convert(varchar(2), DATEPART(month, format([date], 'MM'))) 

[dateid] as cast(DATEPART(YEAR, [date]) as varchar(4))  + cast(DATEPART(day, format( [date], 'DD')) as varchar(2)) + cast(DATEPART(month, format([date], 'MM')) as varchar(2))
```

These statements are under `create table tablename (...)`.

I have tried above syntax and It is showing:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

or

> The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '&' operator.

Can someone help me with this, I want to show date like (YearDayMonth)-`20160111` - how to concatenate these three ?

Comment: If you want to concatenate use `CONCAT` or `+`. Further, it looks like you are trying to save dates as strings, better use `datetime`, `datetime` doesn't have an inherent format.

Comment: I have tried [dateid]  as concat(DATEPART(YEAR,[date]) , DATEPART(day,format( [date],'DD')) , DATEPART(month,format([date],'MM'))) but it is showing Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: You could try `try_convert`, it will convert the values it can convert and returns `null` when it can't. Alternatively, you can give a converting style in your `convert`. This all depends on your data, as there are values it can't convert.

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you just use

```
SELECT FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyddMM')
```

or in your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
(
    .....
    SomeDate DATE,
    DateId AS FORMAT(SomeDate, 'yyyyddMM'),
    ......
 )
```

Comment: how dumb i am :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mogli: happens to everyone - sooner or later - when you're just too deep into something. That's where extra pairs of eyes from e.g. StackOverflow are helpful ! :-) Glad to be of help